# Make ocamlbuild ignore dirs

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

Is there a way to tell ocamlbuild to not go into some dirs?

I have the _tags with the following inside:

```
<dir1> or <dir2>: include
```

But ocamlbuild is saying that there are some .dlls in `dir3` (refusing to build until I clean them), which should not be scanned with that `_tags` configuration. Couldn't get anything in the manual.

I'm on Debian Linux, don't get wrong about the .dlls.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<dir3>: -traverse
```

ocamlbuild traverses all directories recursively by default (more precisely: when _tags or myocamlbuild.ml exists).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the `-` .